# I can't use variable in a function whereHas

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm new with laravel. I can't use $class _id in a function whereHas. What should I do?

```
public function show($classroom_id)
{
    $classrooms = Group::whereHas('members', function ($query) {
        $query->where([['user_id', '=', Auth::id()], ['classroom_id', $classroom_id]]);
    })->get();
    return response()->json($classrooms);
}
```

Comment: Roses Are Red Violets Are Blue Unexpected '{' On Line 32.. Please show some code.

Comment: Add code not screenshot

Comment: accept if it helped

Answer (score 0):

See `use (classroom_id)`

```
   $groups = Group::whereHas('natures', function($q) use($classroom_id)
            {
                $q->where('classroom_id', '=', $classroom_id);

            });
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @Iwanttoknows If you are using PHP 7.4 you can also declare arrow function, this way you don't need to apply the "use ($classroom_id)" because this new kind of functions in PHP inherits parent scope. The code looks like  Group::whereHas('natures', fn($q) => $q->where('classroom_id', $classroom_id));